# How to display only 1 of the array of multiple dropdown value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

May I ask for assistance on how to do this? Dropdown option will hold 2 values, but only 1 of the value will be regonized as its own, and then the 2nd value will only be used for outputting into text fields.

Will it be possible to do it like that?

This is the dropdown.

```
<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown">
    <option value="0">Please select</option>
    <option value="{1:2}">Option 1</option>
    <option value="{3:4}">Option 2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="myreceiver" id="myreceiver" value="" />
```

This is the script

```
$("#mydropdown").change(function () {
    $("#myreceiver").val("Array Value " + this.value);
});
```

Output should display either 1 or 2 for Option 1, and 3 or 4 for Option 2.

EDIT: Would it also be possible for `<option value="{1:2}">Option 1</option>` to be recognized as value: 1 only, and `<option value="{3:4}">Option 2</option>` as value: 4?

Basically what would happen is

```
<option value="{1:2}">Option 1</option> <!-- The data must only be recognized as value 1 as option value will be saved in database --> 
<option value="{3:4}">Option 2</option> <!-- The data must only be recognized as value 3 as option value will be saved in database -->
```

But for `<input type="text" name="myreceiver" id="myreceiver" value="" />`, when you select Option 1 or Option 2, It will recognize as Option 1 = 2, and Option 2 = 4.

What will happen basically in example for Option 1 is `array value 1` will be for dropdown value only, and `array value 2` will only be outputted in input text.

Dropdown Option will hold 2 value, but only 1 will be recognized as its own, and the other value will be used for displaying in text fields.

Comment: What is the expected output? When you say is should display either `1` or `2`, how is this determined? Randomly?

Comment: @atymic if example I only want 1 to show as output? will it be possible?

Comment: and for the second example, you expect to see `3`?

Comment: @atymic I did some edits, is it possible to do it that way? I'm also using ````<select name="mydropdown" id="mydropdown">```` as a variable holder, but I also need it to display a different output in input text. Ex. for option 1, It will only be recognized as value 1, but when it's being outputted to the textbox, it will be recognized as value 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure exactly what you mean, but does this give the expected output?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x9n1b5oh/2/

```js
$("#mydropdown").change(function () {
    let value = this.value.replace(/[{}]/, '').split(':');
    $("#myreceiver").val(value[0]);
    console.log(value[1]) // do something with the second value
});
```

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I'm looking for, my problem now is that I need ````<option value="{1:2}">Option 1</option>```` to only be recognized as value: 2, and ````<option value="{3:4}">Option 2</option>```` to only be recognized as value: 4. As Dropdown values 2 and 4 will ultimately be saved in database as dropdown values.

Comment: Do you control the script that outputs the HTML?

Comment: How is the form submitted?

Comment: ````value="{1:2}"```` are actually column values, but I only need to input 1 into database and 2 will be for output only. So when I change the dropdown, it will also change the text field.

Comment: I'm using ```$_POST```.

Comment: I mean, do you have control of the HTML generation? If so, you should set a `data-display="<display value>"` attribute, which we can then read with JS. That allows you to set the `value` attribute to the correct value so it will work when the form is submitted

Comment: Question, out of context. how to do this into an array ````echo "<option value='".$row['accounttype']."'>".$row['accounttype']."</option>";```` array should be ````$row['accounttype']```` and ````$row['accountcode']````?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197080/discussion-between-pjustindaryll-and-atymic).